# Is it possible to always replace pixels of a certain color in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, gui, pixels, overlay

I would like to mandatorily swap pure white pixels on my PC with another color for example grey, so that the graphics driver never sends out a pure white pixel. All the other pixels of the pc should be the same.

Is there some kind of hack i can use that would work for all programs and every kind of windows overlay mode? a script on the graphics driver/framework? What are the technical challenges to implementing thank kind of tool?

Comment: change the colour temperature; turn down the backlight; rejig your colour profile to a narrower gamut. As it stands, this seems to be a bit of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: That would change all colors on screen. I only want to change absolute white. here is a more promising option... windows desktop supports shader model 2, however i think that''s just aero themes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571331/pixel-vertex-shader-on-top-of-desktop-output

Comment: @ufomorace please tell us your X !!

Comment: If your video driver offers a gamma curve, tweak the endpoint.

Comment: that's a genius comment Fixer... will see. there should be a gamma curve indeed to make a straight line and then the last 1 pixel of the curve at black. the recent nvidia driver doesnt seem to have one, the omega drivers perhaps have it. It just shows that it is possible to change all colors on screen by editing the driver files to have photoshop types of gradients.

Comment: It isn't clear what the issue is with pure white, but if it's a visual thing, there will be hundreds of colors that are virtually white.  Also, adjusting just the "last" pixel of the curve may give you strange color artifacts (and you don't want black, but no lower than the setting as the pixel next to it).  In terms of appearance, the image will look best when it's some type of smooth curve.  You can compress the colors at the end by creating an inflection point near the end and then using a curve that is more horizontal.